# Ruby gem for retrieving details/information on a torrent via info hash

Tags: ruby, rubygems, torrent

Is there a ruby gem that I can use with Ruby or Ruby on Rails that accepts an info hash and returns information on the torrent? Like seeders, leachers, size, etc.?

If not is there any other way I can get this information using Ruby? Is there an API that I can easily digest?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [thepiratebay](https://github.com/emnl/thepiratebay).
Although, it seems like it's not maintained actively anymore. But, should solve your problem.

You can find a torrent:

```
ThePirateBay::Torrent.find("123123123")
```

Also, you can get all the seeders, leechers and size:

```
ThePirateBay::SortBy::Size        # Size, largest first
ThePirateBay::SortBy::Seeders     # Most seeders first
ThePirateBay::SortBy::Leechers    # Most leechers first
```

So, why not giving it a try?

Comment: Thanks, this gem hasn't been updated in 3 years but I may be able to update it myself.

Comment: That sounds great! Let me know if that helps you solve your problem!

Comment: You helped out a lot thanks! Also, I just updated the gem if anyone would like to use it: https://github.com/mhsjlw/thepiratebay

Comment: Awesome! Is it giving you all the seeders, leechers, sizes now?

Comment: Yes. But I'd still like to figure out how to get seeders, leechers and size based off of a hash too. Any ideas? Or will I have to write a ruby client for bittorrent then connect to the torrent everytime I want to get information on it, preferable stand alone and not really using an API

Comment: Taking a quick look, you may want to update this (https://github.com/mhsjlw/thepiratebay/blob/master/lib/thepiratebay/search.rb) file to acommodate your need.

Comment: Yeah I just tested it and it isn't working I'll fix it though.

Comment: I fixed it and added a search example: https://github.com/mhsjlw/thepiratebay/blob/master/API.md#example-search thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends what torrents you are talking about. Different torrent trackers have different APIs.

You might want to dig into specific tracker API (please be mindful these ones are not Ruby APIs):

- https://getstrike.net/api/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/thepiratebay

Comment: I need a Ruby gem so I can't use a nodejs package. Is there any other package that is like the piratebay but in Ruby?